# Putting a newline whenever it match third space

Tags: perl

I have a data that looks like this :

```
 8.620 -9.182 1.758 8.786 -8.249 -0.495 8.614 -9.652 -1.158 9.446 -9.278 
  0.350 11.450 -7.809 0.887 10.638 -9.000 2.070 11.179 -10.871 -1.200 7.583  
 -10.330 0.400 7.079 -9.330 -1.014 6.745 -11.702 0.004 11.610 -12.260 -1.101   
12.381 -13.783 -
```

I want to make three column rows, so whenever it match third space, print new line. Is there some bash command that I can use or how inside the perl script I can change it. This is not a file, I splitted lines according to space, picked up [6,7,8] element and just pushed these elements into an array. When I print array it look unorganized.

This is the part of the script:

```
if ($file_each[$line]=~/^ATOM/)
                {
            $file_each[$line]=~s/^ATOM//;
                    @os=split '\s+', $file_each[$line];
            chomp @os[6,7,8];
            push @coord, @os [6,7,8];
            print "@coord\n";
            }
```

This is how result should look like:

```
8.620 -9.182 1.758  
8.786 -8.249 -0.495  
8.614 -9.652 -1.158
```

Answer (score 0):

If a string `$line` contains your numbers,
try:

```
$line =~ s/(.*?\d +.*?\d .*?\d) +/$1\n/g;
```

We may try it from a file with

```
perl -pe 's/(.*?\d +.*?\d .*?\d) +/$1\n/g' ex
```